# "Caching" mySQL queries, is this an OK practice?

Tags: php, mysql

In my CMS, sometimes I will make redundant queries because everything is independent. Is it ok to cache queries like this?:

```
        global $cache_query, $cache_result;
        if(!is_array($cache_query) || !is_array($cache_result) || !in_array($q,$cache_query))
        {//The query is new. 
            $r = query_($q);
            $cache_query[] = $q;
            $cache_result[] = $r;
        }
        else
        {//The query is cached.
            foreach($cache_query as $k=>$c) // Cycle through my cached queries to find the key. Is there an getElementKey function?
                if($c == $q) {
                    if(@mysql_fetch_array($cache_result[$k])) // is the resource is still valid?
                        mysql_data_seek($cache_result[$k], 0); // rewind the pointer
                    else
                        $cache_result[$k] = query_($q); // reset the resource
                    $r = $cache_result[$k];
                    break;
                }
        }
        return $r;
```

OR is a better practice to just make a new query each time? 
`$q` is my query, and the function `query_()` returns a resource and logs if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database queries are frequently a huge portion of your execution time, so if you can cache them you should.

That said, it might be better to save them off in named variables (or named variables in an associative array). Why are you walking through the array instead of just doing:

```
if(isset($cache_result[$query])) {
    return $cache_result[$query];
} else {
    // not cached
}
```

Comment: I was worried about having too long of an index. Or a `"` being present in the query.

Comment: +1. A suggestion/improvement: As sql queries can get rather large, one can compute the hash value of the SQL query instead of using the query itself as key in the assoc array.

Comment: @Ronnis, I like this. Good Idea.

Comment: @Jason, having a `"` in the query shouldn't cause a problem. Arrays don't need their strings escaped or anything.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks, for some reason I feel like I had a problem with unescaped indices long ago.

Answer (score 3):

You won't get much performance improvements by caching the result resource of a database query. Database engines already provides caching on frequently executed queries, and you still have to convert that resource to an array, which is where most of the overhead comes from.

If you want to improve performance, consider **prepared statements** and **caching the result array** instead of the resource. This way you won't have to process the result over and over, but only get the result actual array from cache.

Comment: Actually, after I posted the question, I realized that I was thinking about it wrong. I would do this, but I can't decide if I'd rather store large arrays in memory or just re-query.

Comment: -1. Apart from the query itself, the greatest overhead is communication between host language and the database server. Reusing an in-memory data structure will be several thousands times faster than reaquiring it from the database.

Comment: @Ronnis, I voted this up because the answer does mention the correct way to do this (caching the result array).

Comment: @Ronnis: You obviously haven't tried it. This widely depends on the database setup. But if you try using a local socket, you will see that parsing the result resource using `mysql_fetch_array` takes longer than executing the database query, even if it already has been executed and cached by the database server.

Comment: @netcoder. Yes, it depends on this and that. But you provided no such information your answer. I'd be happy to upvote your answer instead if it just didn't ignore 3 of the 8 fallacies of distributed computing (Latency is zero, Bandwidth is infinite, Transport cost is zero).

Comment: The answer depends on a lot of variables, in particular the size of the result set.  If the query expense (not bandwidth or latency) is the biggest burden, as the asker implied, then I would agree with netcoder's answer - the server's query cache will automatically get the job done.

Comment: @TehShrike, I agree with everything netcoder wrote. Just not the "which is where most of the overhead comes from" part, because that "depends", and we can't (at least I can't) infer such information from what the OP wrote. If he edited the answer I would upvote it instead, but as it stands it gives the impression that database communication is not a factor when in fact it is.

Answer (score 0):

this is a great question! There is general answer to your question.

In your case, it looks like you make a cache entry to be used for the duration of your page.

It **is** possible for other concurrent transactions to overwrite the database and make your cached results **invalid**, but usually a page is loaded very fast and the possibility of a conflict is rare enough.

Also, it looks like you're **not** creating a banking system, so I guess it's OK.

**REMEMBER**!!! Cache will be destroyed after page load, ie. it **does not** persist across several page loads (each page load will cost at least one query)

Comment: Don't care much about making it persistent. Just on the current page.

Comment: I wanted to tell you that there are no potential issues with your setup, and in your case this can be judged as a good practice, like you asked. In general, caching must be examined with extreme care